# How do you remove a Github repository for Travis CI tests?

Tags: travis-ci

I created a Travis CI test using a Github repository. I can't seem to find any information about how to remove it from the Travis CI test page. Is this at all possible?

Comment: You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52008929/5994041)(I don't want to repeat it).

Answer (score 81):

Yes!

Log in to Travis CI (travis-ci.org) under your account.

Then check on the left sidebar. You should see a `My repositories` label followed by a plus sign (i.e. `+`).

Click on that plus sign (i.e. `+`).

It will lead you to a page listing all your Github repositories with an on/off toggle beside each one.

Just put the toggle to "off" for the repositories you don't want in Travis CI.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. When I hit the plus (+) i get to a page where I'm left with a series of endless expanding and shrinking bubbles and nothing every loads.

Comment: It should work. Maybe Travis CI had some hiccups when you tried. I would suggest to try again.

Comment: Yup, for some reason the it was running extremely slow in all browsers. Now it's working fine.

Comment: Or just re-sync your repositories on that page (after clicking `+`) by clicking the corresponding button.

Comment: This is a pretty bad UI decision from Travis. Click "+" to remove?

Comment: Yep, "click + to remove" is not good UI. It ranks with "Press "Start" to shutdown"

Comment: As of June 2018 you can no longer use the toggle, as the Github integration has changed.

Comment: There is a difference between travis-ci.org and travis-ci.com . The answer works for travis-ci.org.

Answer (score 40):

The accepted answer doesn't appear to work when using the new Travis marketplace app at the time of writing - there's no "on/off" toggle for repositories.

Instead, you need to just grant access to the repositories you want Travis to access in Github. On your profile page in Travis, click "Manage repositories on Github":

[image: manage repositories on Github]

Then, under "Repository access", click "Only select repositories":

[image: only select repositories]

You can then add / remove the repositories you want to show up in the Travis CI test page.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works if you have rights to add the Travis CI app to the org. If you don't, you have to request the owners do so, and since it's all private repos... this is SUPER annoying when you're a member of an org with 180k people and ALL of their clones show up in your sidebar, DESPITE Travis CI not having access to them.

Comment: Wow thank you for that, I never would have found it without this, what a TERRIBLE design why is there no setting directly in travis, thank God for Github actions...

Answer (score 13):

There are two platforms which work differently:

- `travis-ci.org` - for legacy OSS
- `travis-ci.com` - for everything now, recommended over `travis-ci.org` for all new projects

### travis-ci.org

To see and control which repositories of a given organization are enabled on `travis-ci.org`, visit:

```
https://travis-ci.org/organizations/<your-org>/repositories
```

Replacing `<your-org>` with your organization.

Assuming `travis-ci.org` is enabled for your organization, you should see something like this:

[image: travis-ci.org example repository list]

The toggle widget next to each repository controls whether the repository is enabled on `travis-ci.org`.

### travis-ci.com

To see which repositories of a given organization are enabled on `travis-ci.com`, you can visit:

```
https://travis-ci.com/organizations/<your-org>/repositories
```

Replacing `<your-org>` with your organization.

Assuming `travis-ci.com` is enabled for your organization, you should see something like this:

[image: travis-ci.com example repository list]

The "Manage repositories on GitHub" button lets you control, from the GitHub side, which repositories are exposed to `travis-ci.com`.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me...

After deleting the unwanted repositories (In the repository settings, scroll to the bottom and follow deletion instructions), Navigate to [GitHub Repositories](https://github.com/settings/repositories) and 'Leave' the repository if it is still listed.

Navigate to your [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org) Profile, **click 'Sync account** (green button), and the unwanted repos should now be absent.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still confused and are not able to find their way, there are two ways actually.

**First - Via GitHub**

1. Log on to your GitHub account.
2. Click on your profile icon on top-right hand corner and click on settings.
   [image: Github - Account Settings]
3. Navigate to Applications present at the bottom of your side-bar and under "Installed GitHub Apps" click Configure for Travis-CI.
   [image: Configure Travis]
4. Under Repository access, choose "Only select repositories".
   [image: Select Repositories]

**Second - Via Travis**

1. Log on to app.travis-ci.com and navigate to home page/landing page. (Click on the logo)
2. Click on the small + icon present in your side-bar.
   [image: Travis - Settings]
3. Click on Migrate.
   [image: Travis Migrate]
4. Click on "Activate all repositories using GitHub Apps.
   [image: travis - Manage Repo]
5. Select the repositories and you are done.
   [image: Select Repositories]