# How can restart or delete everything on my travis to start over

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

So the thing is that I started using travis and I did not realize that I was working on the master branch instead in the one that I created, I need to get some .img files but I can't because of what I said before.

I have tried everything to move my commits from master to my branch, but it is not possible to get the .img files so I just decided to delete everything and start over.

Can anyone please help me delete everything on my travis without separating travis from github please.

Answer (score 0):

You can [delete Travis log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41274753/6309), not Travis history.

This is a [pending Feature Request from from late 2017](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8883).